# How can I stream file to Mongodb

Tags: javascript

what is the best way to save a small(<16Mb) image file in my mongodb document and how can i achieve that and then how can i get that file and render it to the browser?
Can you please point me to some working example?
Thank's in advance

Comment: Need more detail what webserver ?best way is to upload to file system and store file path in mongo.

Comment: I am still new and so far i am using heroku and node js. So far i can upload files using angular-file-upload and then connect-multiparty on the back end. And i thing if i upload many files i will get some restrictions from heroku. That is the reason I want  to save my files in mongo as binary data, but i cannot get them back as an image.

Comment: If thats a limitation you should use openshift , it have 3GB free storage.